# Will my AMI be a part of the S3 bucket storage or will it be residing in some other storage area, like within EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner in AWS and I'm gathering information about uploading and launching my .vmdk file on AWS. One thing that I'm not sure about is, after I upload my .vmdk to S3 bucket and import it into EC2, will the newly created AMI reside in the S3 bucket along with my uploaded .vmdk file or will be residing in the EC2? Also, will there be charges for storing the AMI as well apart from the .vmdk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will the newly created AMI reside in the S3 bucket along with my
>   uploaded .vmdk file or will be residing in the EC2?

It will be stored in a new S3 bucket, only accessible through the EC2 Instance

> will there be charges for storing the AMI as well apart from the .vmdk
>   file?

Yes, there will be charges for both of them. You could delete the .vmdk once you know your EC2 Instance is correct and you have a valid AMI from that EC2 Instance.

More information here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the reply. If I have my AMI up and running on EC2, and I wanted to share that instance with 5 people, will that mean that there will be 5 separate instances running on cloud? Or will there be 5 different copies created of that instance for 5 people to use? It would be of help if you could share some info on this. Thanks!

Comment: You can share your AMI with different people (accounts). Those accounts will be charged only if they copy your AMI to their account if they choose to do so. Or they can launch new EC2 Instances from your AMI directly if they are in the same Region

Comment: *"It will be stored in a new S3 bucket, only accessible through the EC2 Instance"*  This is incorrect on two counts.  The snapshots accompanying AMIs are not stored in buckets accessible to the user or visible in the S3 console.  The buckets and owned and managed by the EBS service, and invisible to the user, so it's not really accurate to say it's a "new bucket." Also, AMIs are not accessed directly by instances.  Instances have *copies* of the AMI's snapshots as their initial volumes when they launch.  Actions taken on the instance have no effect on the AMI.